# thinly provisioned root partition in Centos 7

Tags: centos, lvm

Seems that my (unbeknownst to me) thinly provisioned root partition was a bit too thin. The system was totally unresponsive, endless messages on console:

```
kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 2449799
kernel: lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
```

At first i suspected faulty disks, but RAID controller seemed happy with them. After hard reset, digged up this gem in /var/log/messages:

```
Jan 22 02:31:31 server kernel: device-mapper: thin: 253:2: reached low water mark for data device: sending event.
Jan 22 02:31:31 server kernel: device-mapper: thin: 253:2: switching pool to out-of-data-space mode
Jan 22 02:32:31 server kernel: device-mapper: thin: 253:2: switching pool to read-only mode
```

Seems that /root is thinly provisioned and has run out of space (kicking myself for accepting Centos install wizard's idea of partitions). I am not too familiar with thin provisioning, so what baffles me, is this:

```
# lvs
  LV     VG     Attr       LSize  Pool   Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  pool00 centos twi-aotz-- 41.66g               100.00 46.82                           
  root   centos Vwi-aotz-- 50.00g pool00        83.33                                  
  swap   centos -wi-ao---- 16.00g
```

Do I understand correctly that there is a pool00 in 50GB vg "centos" that includes logical volumes "swap" and "root"? If so, why does a 50GB pool run out of space if root only uses 14GB of data according to df and swap is 16GB total?

edit:
In an attempt to alleviate the space constraints, I lvremoved partition swap entirely and created it elsewhere. So now:

```
  #lvs
  LV     VG     Attr       LSize  Pool   Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  pool00 centos twi-aotzM- 41.66g               100.00 46.82                           
  root   centos Vwi-aotz-- 50.00g pool00        83.33

#df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   10G   41G  20% /
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G   17M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                497M  154M  343M  31% /boot
```

Somehow i still reach "low water mark" on a 41G pool with one partition that has 10GB of data on it.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Show us the output of `df -h`

Comment: In an attempt to alleviate space constraints I lvremoved partition swap altogether and created it elsewhere. So now pool00 just containst partition root, but i still get  Buffer I/O error on device dm-3 (which is root) almost immediately after boot.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else stumbles upon the same problem i answer to myself:

```
fstrim -v -a
```

or

```
fstrim -v /
```

is the thing that helps. The filesystem does not return unused blocks to the pool, so that they can be reused (by same filesystem in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking to see if the root filesystem can be on a thin provisioned logical volume. It's useful to know that it can.

To answer (and further explain) your question, from the `lvs` output, it would appear that your initial volume group was originally allocated as a standard logical volume `swap` using 16G and a thin privisioned pool logical volume `pool00`. Without the output from `lvs -a`, the size of the underlying metadata logical volume can't be determined; the size of the data volume is 41.66G.

The logical volume `root` was then created as a thin provisioned logical volume on top of `pool00` but was over allocated (or later extended) to be 50G on top of a 41.66G data volume. Presumably, LVM allows this on the assumption that the pool volume will be extended before it get full, but this didn't happen.

As you correctly found, the filesystem does not return blocks to LVM when they are no longer is use, although it will reuse them itself, so although you are only using 14G in actual files, another 27.66G was allocated in from LVM into `root` and then removed from the filesystem, but not actually discarded and returned to LVM. Hence, you ran out of space in the underlying `pool00` volume.

As you correctly determined, running `fstrim` will actually discard unused blocks in the filesystem, notifying LVM that they can be reused and freeing space in `pool00`.

Since you've moved `swap` elsewhere, it would probably be a good idea the use `lvextend` and increase the size of `pool00` to at least 50G, the current size of `root`.

Alternatively, schedule `fstrim` to run every few weeks or so to discard unused blocks.